# How to change header according to navigation drawer

Tags: android

I am using navigation drawer in my application, with fragments. There are icons and text in each row(one of them is products, on clicking these a fragment is open with a list view.After clicking on the list view row i have an activity in this i want header name same as i have selected(products).but bydefault it is showing name off the app which is sales.please help.[image: these are the screen shots]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

pass product name in Intent in your list's onItemClickListner

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),YOURACTIVITY.class);
intent.putExtra("product_name",YOUR PRODUCT_NAME);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

and in your target activity (your product detail activity) put below code in onCreate() method.

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("YOUR DESIRED TITLE");
```

Comment: is it acceptable answer? if yes then accept this answer.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If using `Frament` , you can have a method in parent hosting `Activity` like 
this

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

and invoke this method from your individual fragment like this and set the title

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 //usual statements
 ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Child fragment name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the actionbar header with the following. You can try this.

ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
 actionBar.setTitle("My Title");

Comment: This thing is working fine. but my question is when going to another activity then how to set the header according to the navigation drawer.